# Which text editors support both tabbed windows & rtf documents?

Tags: macos, text, notes.app, tabs, word-processor

I am looking to change my text editor / note taking app for OS X. I require only the following:

- *Tabbed windows*: I don't want every document open in a new window. For some reason this seems to be an elusive feature, missing from even many high end word processors
- Able to handle *rtf documents*
- *Does not* require an account (many note taking apps do)

Pretty short list eh? I'm coming up with almost nothing. 'Bean' (http://www.bean-osx.com/Bean.html) is so far the only one I've found but it's no longer under development and search/replace feature doesn't work properly.

I know this question could be interpreted as open ended or opinion based, but it is not.  I am asking to find out which apps conform to the above requirements, not for opinions about which is best.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [FocusWriter](http://gottcode.org/focuswriter/) to good effect. It supports RTF, has files in independent tabs, and doesn't require a login.

Comment: Thanks.. I had tried that one before but failed to see the tabs because they are hidden by default.  Do you know if there's a way to unhide the tabs without having to hover  over the bottom of the window?

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT: As pointed out below, G.W.'s tabs aren't different docs. This whole response thread can probably safely be deleted.

[Growly Write](http://www.growlybird.com/write/) has those features, and is free!

I was also looking for tabbed windows, and just stumbled on it myself.
It also has an interesting and mostly convenient feature set.

Comment: What features are interesting? i.e. it is better to provide more than just this is a good app

Comment: Mark,
8 months after the question, I'm the first (and only) responder. I've suggested an app that has _precisely_ the 3 features the OP was looking for. I think he will appreciate it!

If you want to know the feature set, just follow the link I also provided.

Comment: See the Help centre "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Comment: Ah, we have different agendas. You want to develop the knowledge base on this site. I just saw a question and wanted to help the guy. I personally don't have the interest to absorb and conform to your protocol, but I respect the effort put into this place as a resource. Good luck with it.

Comment: @pbass wil - Sorry but doesn't meet the requirements. "I don't want every document open in a new window.".  This app offers tabs but they seem to be merely an alternate view of the current document and there is no way that I could find of opening multiple documents in a single tabbed window.

Comment: Dang! You're right billynoah, I hadn't really tested it yet, but sure enough -- tabs are views of the same doc. :^/   Sorry about that; the search continues.